# Dismissing Modal View Controller Causes Multiple VC's to Close

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, segue

[image]

This question is hard for me to ask without a reference, so please see the image above. I am trying to dismiss the modal view controller on the far right of my storyboard.

The problem is when the view controller on the right hand side it dismissed and the user is returned to the middle view controller in the storyboard above, then immediately the next two view controllers are dismissed and the user is returned to the left most view controller.

I have only called the dismiss method on the right most view controller. I am wondering why this happens?

I have fiddled with the kind and presentation style of the segue to no avail. I have also tried using delegation and calling the dismiss method in the presenting view controller. This still results in the same unexpected behavior.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Which method have you been using to dismiss your modal?

Comment: dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion:

Comment: i haven't seen your coed but i think your controller projecthome is also presented and the other are being pushed so when you dismiss it dismisses the parent view and all views are lost

Comment: Post your project on Google Drive or Dropbox so we can see it and test it.